# Getting "internal error" / an unknow error occured with API access google console

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, developer-console

I am trying to connect a Google Cloud Project with my Developer console in order to handle IAP´s.

I tried:

- Creating a new project
- Linking a existing one

I always receive

> An unexpected error occured. Please try again (some error code)

In the web console it says error 500 (internal). I tried to contact Google Support, but unfortunately no useful answers. Can someone help me? I have been trying it for a couple of days now with different approaches (logged out all account, different browsers, devices...) - always the same problem.

Comment: What's your developer console?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the normal play.google android app developer console

Comment: Ok, sorry, I absolutely don't know the android world. I can't help!!

Comment: could you share a little bit more about whats happening? maybe add some screenshots, or any guides that you are using?